# Compile angular 4 for ES-5

Tags: angular, webpack

I have a nasty requirement to support IE11, so I am trying to configure a project to compile for ES-5.

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target":"es5",
    "module":"commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

Here is my `polyfils.ts`:

```
import 'core-js/es6';
// import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import 'ts-helpers';
import 'zone.js';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // Production
    // enableProdMode();
} else {
    // Development
    require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
    Error['stackTraceLimit'] = Infinity;
}
```

As you can see I have imported core-js for shims for es6, but however when I try to compile using webpack I get next errors:

```
@angular\core\src\change_detection\differs\default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts
(24,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
rxjs\Observable.d.ts
(58,60): error TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
@angular\common\src\directives\ng_class.d.ts
(48,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Do you have `@types/core-js` installed? It's either that, or `es2016` in `lib` config section.

Comment: Yes, types for `core-js` is installed.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @Amit, yes I was able to solve this issue.

Comment: Hi Maris, would you mind sharing your solution for this question?

Comment: @KyleVassella sorry, but I don't have that source code already for a long time...